# How to install third party python modules on heroku using pip?

Tags: python, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I have a third party python module forked from github that I want to use in my website. How do I install it on heroku using pip or something else . Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

[Heroku's documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip) contains a detailed write-up on this topic but it all comes down to creating a `requirements.txt` file that contains your dependencies.

You can create this file by dumping currently installed packages with `pip freeze > requirements.txt`